# Parsing rfc 3339 date string with format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' returns nil

Tags: swift, xcode, date, datetime, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert the date string `"2020-05-07T22:59:51Z"` to a `Date` object but have not had any success. This is how I've setup my `DateFormatter` yet I always receive `nil`:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

In addition I have tried:

- Making the formatter `static`
- Changing the dateFormat string to `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"`, `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`, `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"`, `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"`
- Following the Apple documentation for [Working With Fixed Format Date Representations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) (by first replacing the single occurrence of `"Z"` with `"-00:00"` to match RFC 3339 format, ex. `"2020-05-07T22:59:51-00:00"`)
- Digging into the Apple documentation archives and following the [Parsing an RFC 3339 date-time](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html) example

Here is a snippet where I use the date formatter above to try and parse `"2020-05-07T22:59:51Z"`. `dateString` is not `nil` and this is happening on the main thread as well:

```
if let dateString = readASN1DateString(ptr: &dateStartPtr, maxLength: length) {
    receiptCreationDate = Receipt.RFC3339DateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
}
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Thanks for the response and comments, funny enough when I put a raw string inside it works, but when I have a String variable with the EXACT same string it returns nil. Here are a couple images showing what I see when debugging:

[Step over print(...), Step over self.receiptCreationDate = ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI0nC.png)

[Console log after print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC9QK.png)

[self.receiptCreationDate = nil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5yy4.png)

[value of dateString](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsP5V.png)

One thing to note is that the String returned by `readASN1DateString(...)` is initialized using `String(bytesNoCopy:, length:, encoding: .ascii, freeWhenDone: false)`

Comment: have you tried printing `dateString` before parsing it to make sure your date string is correct?

Comment: Your date format is wrong. You should NOT escape the Z. Z means timezone if you escape it your date format will ignore the timezone on your string. "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX" is the correct format

Comment: Use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter. That’s what it’s for. Stop trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @matt OP is following an outdated documentation go easy on him

Comment: already tried ISO8601DateFormatter, didn't work. Edited the original post to show debug output

Comment: @JSchiavo you issue it is not in your date formatter it is probably in your readASN1DateString method

Comment: Did you look at the images showing the debug output? The dateString is a valid string and it matches the raw string from the print statement above, character for character

Comment: can you put a print statement before parsing your string and check its value?

Comment: That's the print of the optional Date? object returned after calling Receipt.RFC3339DateFormatter.date(from: "2020-05-08T03:03:54Z"). Printing out the dateString inside the if let shows the exact same value as the debug inspector "DATESTRING: 2020-05-08T03:03:54Z"

Answer (score 0):

I am using your code and getting the output

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
  formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  let isoDate = "2020-05-07T22:59:51Z"
  if let date = formatter.date(from:isoDate) {
   print(date)
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with a raw string the formatter works fine. But for some reason a string variable with the exact same string returns nil when passed in. Edited the post to show debug output

Comment: @JSchiavo the date is there... just use `po` on lldb and you will see it.